# Twitter API getting any user's all tweets

Tags: php, twitter

I am newly started searching the twitter API and to gain time I would like to ask and hope to learn about that. Which method of Twitter API can give me someone's all tweets between a date period. (I will set that user and date period. And using PHP)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None.

Twitter API has limitations and this is quite understandable because of the number of tweets in the database and the load that could be created by such queries.

You may use [user_timeline](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/user_timeline) however, if last 3,200 updates will suffice.

**EDIT**: I have corrected my answer following Jessycat's answer (was: 32,000 tweets, changed to 3,200 tweets).

Comment: Hey Tadeck, There is not sufficient explanation about the user_timeline so I would like to ask you that. When I use this: 
$content = $connection->get('statuses/user_timeline', array('screen_name' => 'mytwittername')); It won't work. How can I access that 32000 update?

Comment: @gencay The single request can get you up to 200 tweets (see: [count parameter](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/user_timeline) in the documentation). To access these 32000 tweets, you will have to make 160 requests (32000/200). Thus you will have to read about [rate limiting](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/rate-limiting) (and probably employ some walkaround techniques listed there, or try to convince Twitter you really need that). As I said, Twitter API has to be limited because of the amount of data etc.

Comment: @Jessicat: Apparently I have made a typo, and then based my comment on it. Will correct the answer

Answer (score 3):

i think you can use since and until operators offered by the search api

check:
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search
the operators part.

an example would be:
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=egypt&since=2011-11-28&until=2011-11-30

Answer (score 1):

For the standard Twitter API, you can't do that, you can only get tweets since a certain tweet id, and even then you're capped at how many tweets you can get back.

For the search API, I tried a few methods using the `until` parameter, but could not get anything useful out of it.